# how to store a string using array in c?

Tags: c

in php

```
$arr = array()
$arr[0] = "string 1";
$arr[1] = "string 2";
```

how about in c?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare an array of pointers. Each element of the array is a pointer to the string. You need to copy the string in, and then release it when done.

```
char *strings[2];

strings[0] = strdup("Hello, world!");
printf("%s\n", strings[0]);
free(strings[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do that:

- This will allocate enough space in
  the data segment of the program to
  store the string, and store the
  address of the string, in the "arr"
  variable, which can then be accessed
  just like an array.

> ```
> char *arr = "First String";
> char a = arr[2];
> ```

- Another way is to allocate memory
     for the string and then store it in
     that memory which can subsequently
     be accessed like an array:

> ```
> char a;
> char *str = (void *) malloc(14);
> strncpy(str, "Second String", 14);
> a = str[2];
> ```

- Third way is to just declare an array
  of a certain size and assign a string
  to it:

> ```
> char str[14] = "Third String";
> ```

**Here is a [good discussion](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Pointers_and_arrays) of Arrays and Pointers in C.**